# Fitting GLMMs for RT data with different condition level distributions

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, gamma-distribution, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I have RT data that I'm looking to analyse. RT data usually follows Gamma/Inverse-Gaussian shape distributions, thus I usually fit a glmer model (in R) specifying the family as either of those distributions and assessing the best fit using the AIC() function.

However I have some RT data that is slightly different to what I usually get. Two of my conditions follow the Gamma/Inverse-Gaussian  shapes, but my other two conditions follow relatively normal distributions.

[image]

So now I'm wondering, is there an analysis technique that can account for different conditions having different distributional shapes? I'm using the lme4 package in R and I actually find that a linear mixed effects model provides a better fit to these data than a GLMM with Gamma or Inverse-Gaussian distribution family. I'm not aware of technique that can account for this (or whether it's actually necessary) but perhaps someone can provide some insight.

Cheers.

Comment: Wow, never seen this before. I know that in brms you can specify distributional models with a different error term by group, but I don't really know if that would help here. I'm going to follow this question as I'm very interested in what more knowledgeable people have to say.